# read (pull) vs pipe(control flow) vs data(push)

Tags: node.js

Node.js has different options to consume the data.
Streams 0,1,2,3 and so on...

My question is with respect to real life application of
These different option. I fairly understand the 
Difference between readable /read, data event and 
Pipe but not very confident about selecting specific
Method.

For example if I want to use flow control, read with
Some manual work as well as pipe can be used.
data event ignores flow control, should I stop using
Plain data event?

Comment: Perhaps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgEuZ52OZtU is of help :-)

Comment: Thanks Golo Roden, so far best video on streams. I liked "array over time" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For most things, you should be able to use

```
src.pipe(dest);
```

If you look at [the source code for the Stream.prototype.pipe implementation](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/stream.js#L46-L127), you can see that it's just a very handy wrapper that sets everything up for you

For all the work I do with streams, I generally just choose the proper stream type (`Readable`, `Writable`, `Duplex`, `Transform`, or `PassThrough`) and then define the proper methods (`_read`, `_write`, and/or `_transform`) on the stream. Lastly, I use `.pipe` to connect everything together.

It's very common to see stream setups that appear to be "circular"

```
client.pipe(encoder).pipe(server).pipe(decoder).pipe(client)
```

---

As an example, here's stream I'm using in my [burro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/burro) module. You can **write** objects to this stream, and you can **read** JSON strings from it.

```
// burro/encoder.js
var stream  = require("stream"),
    util    = require("util");

var Encoder = module.exports = function Encoder() {
  stream.Transform.call(this, {objectMode: true});
};

util.inherits(Encoder, stream.Transform);

Encoder.prototype._transform = function _transform(obj, encoding, callback) {
  this.push(JSON.stringify(obj));
  callback(null);
};
```

As a general recommendation, you will almost always write your Streams like this. That is, you write your own "class" that inherits from one of the built-in streams. It is not really practical for you to use a built-in stream directly.

---

To demonstrate how you might use this, start by creating a new instance of the stream

```
var encoder = new Encoder();
```

See what the encoder outputs by piping it to stdout

```
encoder.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Write some sample objects to it

```
encoder.write({foo: "bar", a: "b"});
// '{"foo":"bar","a":"b"}'

encoder.write({hello: "world"});
// '{"hello":"world"}'
```

Comment: Thanks naomik. My question was mainly for built in streams not custom/user defined stream.

Comment: @PK, I'm glad you phrased it exactly like that. You're not really supposed to use the built-in stream objects directly. You're meant to "subclass" them. Please see my updated post.